# GitLab behind nginx doesn't work

Tags: linux, nginx

My GitLab is running on port 9999 and it can be accessed using the below URL

http://server01.example.com:9999/ (which redirects to http://server01.example.com:9999/users/sign_in)

or it can be directly accessed on the below URL
http://server01.example.com:9999/users/sign_in

I have configured nginx to listen on port 443. Here is how my current configuration looks like,.

```
server {
        client_max_body_size 40M;
        listen 443;
        server_name server01.example.com;

        location /gitlab/ {
                rewrite ^/.* http://$server_name/gitlab/users/sign_in permanent;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999/users/sign_in/;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

When I try to access http://server01.example.com:443/gitlab/

It is getting redirected to the following URL,

http://server01.example.com/gitlab/users/sign_in

and tell me that "page not found error". Nginx error log shows me the following.

```
2018/07/15 07:09:37 [error] 20300#0: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/gitlab/users/sign_in" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: _, request: "GET /gitlab/users/sign_in HTTP/1.1", host: "server01.example.com"
```

**Update1:**

**Current Configuration:**

```
server {
        client_max_body_size 40M;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name server01.example.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tlscert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;

        location /gitlab/ {
                rewrite ^/.* https://$server_name/gitlab/users/sign_in/ permanent;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999/;
                proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:9999/ https://$server_name/gitlab/;
        }
}
```

> https://server01.example.com/gitlab/users/sign_in
>
> This page isn’t working server01.example.com redirected you too many
>   times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: If you are offering any internal Gitlab service to public network via http, you can consider all code on that repository as open access to everyone. I hope the code on the server is not critical to your business.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: Based on this configuration sample we are expecting some remarkably high quality code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be useful if you specify your nginx version (gitlab version, linux distribution and version wouldn't hurt either).

I would probably use a few tweaks in your config, disable the redirect and send the headers for the proxy:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name server01.example.com;

        client_max_body_size 40M;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tlscert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;

        location /gitlab/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999/;
                proxy_redirect    off;

                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;

        }
}
```

If that doesn't work ([it will depend on your nginx version](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)) I would try something with a rewrite, like:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name server01.example.com;

        client_max_body_size 40M;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tlscert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;

        location /gitlab/ {
                rewrite ^/gitlab(/.*)$ $1 break;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999/;
                proxy_redirect    off;

                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;

        }
}
```

But I would leave the redirect off either way. I think that's causing your problems.

Comment: thank you the first_one helped. One last query, is there any difference between `location ^~ /gitlab/` and `location  /gitlab/`.  The  nginx version is (1.12.2)

Comment: Glad it worked. Please mark the answer as correct if it was useful. Regarding the ```location``` , yes, there is a difference The one with ```^~``` , is a carat and tilde modifier has priority on match. if present, and if this block is selected as the best non-regular expression match, regular expression matching will not take place. I did an answer about the location priorities in another question, if I find it later I will link it here.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you redirect to `http://`, not `https://`:

> ```
> rewrite ^/.* http://$server_name/gitlab/users/sign_in permanent;
> ```

Also, with `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999/users/sign_in/;` your `/gitlab/` only has the login page. Based on your `rewrite`, you are not trying to do that. Shouldn't you have e.g.

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 40M;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name server01.example.com;
    # All the missing SSL configuration

    location /gitlab/ {
        #rewrite ^/gitlab/$ https://$server_name/gitlab/users/sign_in permanent;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999/;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:9999/ https://$server_name/gitlab/;
    }
}
```

GitLab already doing the redirection, the `rewrite` might be unnecessary with `proxy_redirect`.

Comment: Certainly it wouldn't. With `http://example.com` the browser connects to port `80`. In that case, the URL should be `http://example.com:443`, explicitly specifying the port. But it's ridiculously easy to add TLS protection with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and you really should take that step.

Comment: The `^/.*` has everything including the redirect destination. Should it be `^/gitlab/$` alone? I fixed it and also made it a comment as I believe it would even work without, GitLab already doing it through `proxy_redirect`.